# R st_read works fine on windows but fails on linux

Tags: r, download

Am trying to download the following data. It works fine on a windows machine but on a linux server it returns the error

"Error: Cannot open "https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=en"; The file doesn't seem to exist.
In addition: Warning message:
GDAL/OGR not compiled with libcurl support, remote requests not supported. (GDAL error 6)"

```
library(sf)

countries <- st_read("https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=en")
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, it works in ubuntu-20.04 with R-4.1.2. The error (with gdal/ogr) suggests you are doing more to produce the error, not just downloading the files. (Or perhaps I'm missing something else.)

Comment: Really sorry, I posted the wrong bit of the script. It was an st_read instead and different link!

Answer (score 0):

A work around is:

```
download.file("https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/world-administrative-boundaries/download/?format=geojson&timezone=Europe/Berlin&lang=en", 
                           destfile = "world_map.geojson")

countries <- st_read("world_map.geojson")
```

But would be good to know why is different on windows and linux.